Advanced SQL Server LIKE pattern
I am working with a SQL Server 2019 machine, and a single table that is a list of file names and other details about the file. There are over 2 million rows in this table.
We are using a .NET framework 4.6 app to query this table. We want to filter the rows based on this pattern but I can't think of a way to write it. Even chatGPT can't seem to write it, but I feel like there is some way to do it that I'm missing. The problem i keep having is that it doesn't seem that SQL Server has a way of looking for a character or not a character, kind of like it was optional.
The pattern:

Starts with three numbers either a dash, underscore, or nothing
Three more numbers
Either a dash, underscore, or nothing
Three more numbers
Then anything

Example entries that should work:
123-456789 somethnljdsflkjsdf.ext
123456789 newsomething.ext
123_456_789 jlkajsdfkl.ext

Here is what I've come up with so far:
SELECT * 
FROM [#testingTable] AS [tt] 
WHERE [tt].[TestingValue] LIKE '012[_-]%325[_-]%020[_-]%000'


"I am working with a SQL Server 2019" then why tag [[tag:sql-server-2012]]? Please make sure to tag correctly.

I'd do something like this:
SELECT *
FROM [#testingTable] AS [tt]
WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE([tt].[TestingValue], '-', ''), '_', '') LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'


Would also match -1_2-3456789 newsomething.ext as it just strips them out regardless of position

Thanks! That worked. I never thought about removing the extra characters. I think Martin's works as well, but i feel like this is the better because it will expand for us later if we add more conditions.

There is no syntax for optional characters from a set in the SQL Server pattern syntax.
Given that the underscore and dash checks can be combined you've only got 4 permutations so can just list them out
WHERE   TestingValue LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
     OR TestingValue LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][_-][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
     OR TestingValue LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][_-][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
     OR TestingValue LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][_-][0-9][0-9][0-9][_-][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'

